# Tkinter socket sending data error while opening the server and client

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, login-system

Got an error of: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied when using socket with tkinter on login between server and client
Server :

```
    import socket
import pickle
import datetime


# Socket settings
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # socket setting
my_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1024)) # binding the server ip
my_socket.listen(10) # how much people can join the server
client_socket, client_address = my_socket.accept() # accepting the people if the server is available
print("Server Open") # prints that the server is open

# Functions

def get_users():
    # get from the login_users.txt all users & passwords
    # format in file - username|password
    logs = []
    with open('login_users.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            cur = line.strip('\n\r')
            cur = cur.split("|")
            logs.append(cur)
        f.close()
    return logs

def get_rank(user):
    # get from the ranks.txt all users & passwords
    # format in file - username|password
    ranks = []
    with open('ranks.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            cur = line.strip('\n\r')
            cur = cur.split("|")
            ranks.append(cur)
        f.close()
    for r in ranks:
        if r[0] == user:
            return r[1]

def add_to_logs(user, line):
    # add attempt to record (logs_.txt)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    with open('logs_.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(line + " " + str(now) + "\n")
        f.close()

def user_exist(user):
    for log in logs:
        if log[0] == user:
            return True

def check(user, password):
    # check the password that the user typed
    # if there are 3 failed tried disable the login button
    global logs
    global atmp
    global null_state
    global login_state
    global logged_user
    global status
    # get text from boxes:
    user = user.get()
    password = password.get()
    print("user: ", user)
    print("pass: ", password)
    # add attempt to logs_ file
    add_to_logs(user, f"{user} has tried to log in.")
    atmp += 1
    if user_exist(user):
        null_state = False
        for log in logs:
            if log[0] == user and log[1] == password:
                # pop up login succeed
                login_state = True
                logged_user = user
                status = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    btpressed = pickle.loads(my_socket.recv(1024))
    if btpressed:
        client_socket.send(pickle.dumps([status]))
        username, password = pickle.loads(my_socket.recv(1024))  # Getting data from the server
        status = check(username, password)
        print(status)
```

client:

```
    import socket
import pickle
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
import tkinter.font as tkFont

user_send = "nothing"
pass_send = "nothing"

# Socket settings
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # setting the socket
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1024))  # joining the server
print("Connected to the server successfully!")

def check_null(user, password):
    global null_state
    # check for the username and password in the file:
    if user == "" or password == "" or user == "" and password == "":
        null_state = True
        fail_msg = "Please make sure you have entered username and password in both fields!"
        mb.showinfo(title="Enter username and password", message=fail_msg)

#def display_system():
    #root1.title("Secure4U")
    #root1.geometry("1200x600")
    #fontStyle = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=20)
    #show_user_logged = tk.Label(root1, text="Hello " + logged_user + ",", font=fontStyle)
    #show_user_logged.pack(side="top", anchor="nw")
    #user_rank =
    #show_user_rank = tk.Label(root1, text="Rank: " + str(user_rank), font=fontStyle)
    #show_user_rank.pack(side="top", anchor="nw")
    #root1.mainloop()  # run tkinter display

def display_login():
    global log_button
    # initiate and display all objects on screen
    root.title("Secure4U Login")
    root.geometry("450x250")
    fontStyle = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=20)

    # user name
    user_label = tk.Label(root, text="Username:", font=fontStyle)
    # user_box = tk.Text(root, bg="grey", height=1, width=20, font=fontStyle)
    user_box = tk.Entry(root, bg="grey", font=fontStyle)
    user_label.pack()
    user_box.pack()

    # password
    pass_label = tk.Label(root, text="Password:", font=fontStyle)
    # pass_box = tk.Text(root, bg="grey", font=fontStyle)
    pass_box = tk.Entry(root, bg="grey", font=fontStyle, show="*")
    pass_label.pack()
    pass_box.pack()

    # login button
    log_button = tk.Button(root, text='Login', height=2, width=20, command=lambda:(button_pressed()))
    log_button.pack()
    user_send = user_box
    pass_send = pass_box
    root.mainloop()  # run tkinter display

def button_pressed():
    BtPressed = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global BtPressed
    BtPressed = False
    status = False
    my_socket.send(pickle.dumps([BtPressed]))
    if not status:
        null_state = False # checks if the user entered null data on one or both of the fields
        root = tk.Tk()
        display_login()
        if BtPressed:
            my_socket.send(pickle.dumps([user_send, pass_send]))  # Sending data to the server
            status = pickle.loads(my_socket.recv(1024))  # Getting data from the server
    # success_msg = f"Hello {logged_user}, you logged in successfully!"
    # mb.showinfo(title="login succeed!", message=success_msg)
```

I don't know what it happened and I tried everything, please help me if you can
Thank you :)

Comment: *" I tried everything,"* - which says exactly nothing about what you actually tried. Currently you just provide code dumps and some error messages - where it is not clear which process (client or server) the error message produces and where exactly. Also there is likely lots of irrelevant code here so please reduce it to the bare minimum needed to show the problem. See also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In server side, should `btpressed = pickle.loads(my_socket.recv(1024))` be `btpressed = pickle.loads(client_socket.recv(1024))` instead?

Comment: Yep, thank you :)